# Type conversions of slices and interfaces

Tags: go, interface, slice

If I have a function passed an `interface{}` that I can determine (through other means) is a slice, but not what it is a slice of, how can I iterate through it (preferably without using reflection)?

Here is an MCVE (very simplified from my actual code). `forEach` is a function which iterates through the a slice, the type of which is "lost" in the call stack from main(). It seeks to say *"aha, a slice, I will iterate through it a a slice of `interface{}` and call the passed-in `onEach` function on each value"*. This fails because the type 'conversion' fails thus:

```go
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []string, not []interface {}
```

I know full well why the type 'conversion' fails, i.e. it's not really a type conversion, it's an assertion. However given (if only I could iterate) I could assert in respect of each slice member, this should in principle be doable.

Let's assume I actually want an iterator like `forEach` which can do this (as opposed to a `forEachString`, `forEachInt` etc.). Is there a good way to do this? Preferably without reflection (though I guess that's OK), but certainly without reflection involving a case for each type (which was the point of having the `forEach` function in the first place)?

I am aware the (as yet unimplemented) Generics proposal would work super well for this, but I'd like to do this with existing technology!

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type onEach func(x interface{})

func printString(x interface{}) {
    xx := x.(string)
    fmt.Printf("x is a string '%s'\n", xx)
}

func printInt(x interface{}) {
    xx := x.(int)
    fmt.Printf("x is an int '%d'\n", xx)
}

func forEach(y interface{}, onEach onEach) {
    // code to ensure y is a slice omitted
    a := y.([]interface{}) // <-------- THIS LINE PANICS
    for _, x := range a {
        onEach(x)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"foo", "bar"}
    i := []int{1, 2, 3}
    forEach(s, printString)
    forEach(i, printInt)
}
```

Comment: You can either enumerate all possible slice types, or use reflection. There is no other way.

Comment: @JimB i.e. use `Value.Len()`, `Value.Index()`, etc? I guess that's what I'll have to do - sigh.

Comment: @JimB OK - added an answer to that effect with example code in case anyone else should need this.

Answer (score 2):

So here is an answer using reflection, which is I guess not too ugly.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type onEach func(x interface{})

func printString(x interface{}) {
    xx := x.(string)
    fmt.Printf("x is a string '%s'\n", xx)
}

func printInt(x interface{}) {
    xx := x.(int)
    fmt.Printf("x is an int '%d'\n", xx)
}

func forEach(y interface{}, onEach onEach) {
    // code to ensure y is a slice omitted
    v := reflect.ValueOf(y)
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        onEach(v.Index(i).Interface())
    }
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"foo", "bar"}
    i := []int{1, 2, 3}
    forEach(s, printString)
    forEach(i, printInt)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the reflect package to write an iteration function over a slice of an arbitrary type:

```
// forEach calls f for each element of slice s.
// The function f must have a single argument with
// the same type as the slice's element type.
func forEach(s interface{}, f interface{}) {
    sv := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    fv := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    for i := 0; i < sv.Len(); i++ {
        fv.Call([]reflect.Value{sv.Index(i)})
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
func printString(s string) {
    fmt.Printf("x is a string %q\n", s)
}

s := []string{"foo", "bar"}
forEach(s, printString)
```

This answer is different from code in the question and another answer in that the function `f` does not need to use a type asssertion.